# .Net Core 2 IHttpContextAccessor returns WindowsPrincipal even when auth is Claims based

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to use the IHttpContextAccessor in my .net core 2.0 web api and when I access the context it is always a WindowsPrincipal even though I can clearly see that my auth config works(jwt bearer) fine and in TokenValidated, the HttpContext there has my ClaimsPrincipal and my claims.  Why isn't the IHttpContextAccessor using the correct HttpContext. Its registered with services via the DI like it is supposed to.  Anybody have any idea?  This is using httpsys listener under Service Fabric.

Here's more information:

This line is the LAST line to configure IServiceCollection 'services'

`services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

This is AFTER authentication(AddJwtBearer), authorization policies, data protection, CORS, etc.

I am using Serilog with custom Enrichers that enrich the data written to the logs with HttpContext information.  Those enrichers are initialized with the IHttpContextAccessor reference so they can call on the HttpContext to get certain information from it to log.  When logs are written when there is not http context then it ignores this, but when logs are written inside controller action, then it should be able to get the data from the context.  If I set a breakpoint and compare the HttpContext directly in the controller to what is in the HttpContext that the IHttpContextAccessor has, they are different.  The regular one available directly in the controller shows my ClaimPrincipal with claims, but the IHttpContextAccessor one shows a WindowsPrincipal with no claims but it does have the url and query string, etc.

I figured the order may affect it and that is why I put it AFTER configuration of the other items.

This is using HttpSysCommunicationListener in a Service Fabric service.

Comment: can you paste the codes used to add `IHttpContextAccessor` singleton and how you injected it

Comment: have you checked the order of `AddAuthentication` and `AddSingleton`?

Comment: I added a little more information above. I tried with the singleton being added before auth and after thinking it may make a difference. Same result though.

Answer (score 0):

After taking another look and thinking about Neville's question, I moved the IHttpContextAccessor singleton AND the piece that retrieves it and wires it into my code and was able to confirm that it picked up the ClaimsPrincipal.  It will be the windows principal for all logs that are not in the context of an http request as expected.